# response.data different outputs - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and been a while since I didn't use javascript, my knowledge is limited and my question may seem stupid.

I have been following this tutorial which was a bit out of date before Currency Convert API have changed their JSON responses (if that we call them).

So I used axios to get the API and this code below works perfectly

```
const key = this.from+'_'+this.to;
                const apiConv = axios.get('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q='+key+'&compact=ultra&apiKey=API_KEY///');
                apiConv.then(response =>{
                    console.log(response);
                    this.result = response.data[key];
```

My question here is as the following:
if `const key = this.from+'_'+this.to;` = USD_EUR means `this.result = response.data.key;` must work! But I get `undefined`, when I try `this.result = response.data.USD_EUR;` works with no problems and I get my value while `key = USD_EUR`

This is the data I get from `console.log(response);`

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}data: USD_EUR: 0.87961__proto__: Objectheaders: {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}status: 200statusText: ""__proto__: Object
```

Can anyone please explain to me why I have to add `data[key]` to get the value and `data.key` doesn't work

Comment: You should add the `javascript` tag to the question - as the question has to do more with javascript, less with vue.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data[key] supports variable keys, while data.key doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use `data.key`, you are asking JavaScript to get an item named `key` (not `USD_EUR`) from the `data` object. Since your `data` does not contain a value against `key` (literally `key`, not the *value of `key`*), it will give you `undefined`.

When you use `data[key]`, then you are asking JavaScript to get the value of an item **represented** by the `key` variable. In this case, JavaScript will figure out that `key` has the value `USD_EUR` and try to get `data.USD_EUR` and you will get your value.

Remember - the dot notation is for when the child key is **not dynamic**. You cannot use the dot notation to get values from keys whose names are dynamic. In such cases, you always need to use the array accessing pattern (using `object.[key]`).